# «Благодаря» в отрицательном контексте

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые, выбор-слов, предлоги

> Вдобавок этот скромный товарищ в солдатском френче страшную войну выиграл, могучую империю построил, мощное войско создал, которого весь мир боялся, включая Америку. Гигантские заводы возвел, новые города. Атомную бомбу сделал. Боевые ракеты.
>   — Но при этом с людьми не считался,[?] и десятки миллионов уморил — и в войну, **благодаря своему бездарному командованию**, и в репрессиях.
>   [Анна и Сергей Литвиновы. Мертвые не лгут](https://books.google.ee/books?id=av5DDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT89&lpg=PT89&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85&source=bl&ots=aacaq5Oqbh&sig=eEtpFWWLciBJPsicIGiyeRuCdZ8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjToaqt887bAhVB3SwKHUAYBN8Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85&f=false)

Возникло два вопроса к одному предложению:
1. Правильно ли использовано слово "благодаря" (ведь это отрицательный контекст)?
2. Крутила-вертела, но так и не смогла найти правило, которое бы объяснило постановку запятой после слова "считался". Подскажите.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в контексте полемики приём замены обычного "из-за" на "благодаря" (ср. "заклятые друзья" и пр.) оправдан: это своего рода приближение к языку оппонента, систематически используемому им по отношению к персонажу во френче, стремление донести свою мысль его, оппонента, языком.

Основания для постановки запятой можно усмотреть как в интонационном авторском аспекте, так и в том, что предложения, между которыми стоит союз "и", находятся в причинно-следственной связи ("и" можно трактовать как "поэтому/потому/в результате"): "не считался, в результате - уморил".

Answer (score 2):

**Но при этом с людьми не считался, и десятки миллионов уморил — и в войну, благодаря своему бездарному командованию, и в репрессиях.**

Из словаря Кузнецова: БЛАГОДАРЯ, предлог. кому-чему. Из-за кого-, чего-л., по причине, вследствие чего-л. (обычно при указании **на положительный, желаемый результат).**

1) Оборот "благодаря своему бездарному командованию" может иметь **иронический смысл,** сравнить: Забил заряд я в пушку туго И думал: угощу я друга! Гвоздин, хозяин превосходный, Владелец нищих мужиков.

С другой стороны, в приведенном примере ирония **не читается однозначно** и поэтому может быть понята как речевая ошибка (это **недостаток** текста).

2) **Запятая авторская, соответствует паузе.** Её назначение — разделить текст на две части, так как присоединительная конструкция в большей степени **конкретизирует вторую часть**.

Answer (score 2):

В пособии "А как лучше сказать?" Д. Э. Розенталь, о предлоге "благодаря" сказано:

Предлог **благодаря**, не потерявший еще своего первоначального
**лексического значения (по связи с глаголом благодарить),** естественнее употреблять в тех случаях, когда речь идет о причинах, **вызывающих желательный результат, например: выздоровел благодаря
правильному лечению, выиграл партию благодаря тонкому понима-
нию сложной позиции; ср.: Благодаря выпавшему снегу можно было
кое-что рассмотреть на земле (Арсеньев). Встречающиеся в печати
обороты «благодаря снежным заносам движение на транспорте
прервано», «поезд потерпел крушение благодаря небрежности
стрелочника» и т. п. воспринимаются как нарушение указанного
положения («не за что благодарить»).**

Вместе с тем следует отметить **широкое употребление предлога
благодаря не только в разговорном, но и в книжном стиле для указания причины вообще; такая причина может быть нейтральной или
даже вызывающей отрицательные последствия**. *Ср.: ...Связь с людьми
потеряна благодаря последним арестам (Горький); Последние дни
благодаря дурной погоде он пил по вечерам слишком много (Бунин);
С войны он вернулся почти оглохший, благодаря осколку гранаты,
с больной ногой... (Куприн). Однако невозможность оборотов типа
«не пришел на работу благодаря смерти матери» показывает, что
до некоторой степени в предлоге благодаря сохраняется его первона-
чальное значение.*

Такого же мнения придерживаются и авторы Русской академической грамматики. Там сказано:

> «Позитивный оттенок значения предлога в современном языке утрачен: успех благодаря настойчивости, опоздали благодаря аварии; Все неприятности – благодаря соседке; Благодаря матери в семье снова мир» **(Т. 2. М., 1980, с. 445).**
>      Если благодаря – деепричастие от глагола благодарить, то род. п. нормален: Вышел из комнаты, благодаря (= говоря благодарности) своего друга за помощь. Вернулись с рыбалки, благодаря небо за отсутствие дождя.»

Comment: Из словаря Кузнецова: БЛАГОДАРЯ, предлог. кому-чему. Из-за кого-, чего-л., по причине, вследствие чего-л. (обычно при указании на положительный, желаемый результат). Примеры взяты не из современной литературы.  Думаю, что положительный смысл исходного глагола в предлоге не утрачен (даже, может быть, восстановлен), иначе возможно  его ироническое восприятие.

Comment: Jasmin, не все пособия по стилистики разделяют эту точку зрения. Розенталь также отмечает, что, хотя, такое употребление возможно, но нежелательно.

Comment: Здесь интересна направленность процесса, то есть к чему мы сейчас движемся: к общему варианту или только положительному. Классики свободно использовали общее значение,  а у наших современников оно не всегда одобряется.

Comment: @Серж А по поводу запятой умозаключения есть? Хотелось бы знать Ваше мнение.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду после считался?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, запятая в данном случае не нужна. Это неполное двусоставное предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что запятая не нужна (указала это в вопросе), если следовать правилам. Но как _авторская_ — возможна?

Comment: Нет, в правилах пунктуации такой случай не описан. Поскольку даже авторская пунктуация не должна выходить за рамки языка. Иначе любой автор будет "лепить" знаки препинания там, где ему угодно. Оправдывая это авторским замыслом.