# Корректно так писать: "Войско, которого весь мир боялся"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> ...мощное войско создал, которого весь мир боялся.

Слова эти, взятые из другого вопроса (["Благодаря" в отрицательном контексте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441308/%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)), режут мне слух, но никак не могу понять, что тут не так.

"Создал робота, которого весь мир боялся" -  нормально.
"Создал **то** войско, которого весь мир боялся" -  нормально.
"Создал войско, которого весь мир боялся" — ?!

Может, дело в том, что который — это скорее "один из"?

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: А Вы — _замечательный_ читатель! Я тоже видела ЭТУ особенность, но решила, что **три** вопроса к одному контексту — это много.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Спасибо! И у Вас чувство дискoмфорта возникло? Однако из ответов следует, что все в порядке...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я бы написал так: "Такое мощное войско создал, что (его) весь мир боялся".

Comment: В этом предложении ЧТО - это союз со значением следствия,  а у него правильная позиция, в отличие от союзного слова КОТОРЫЙ, поэтому и читается предложение лучше. Местоимение ЕГО надо  использовать в обязательном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Вдобавок этот скромный товарищ в солдатском френче страшную войну выиграл, могучую империю построил, **мощное войско создал, которого весь мир боялся, включая Америку.**

Существуют **два варианта определительных  придаточных:** выделительный (тот/такой, который...) и распространительный (который...).

В приведенном предложении использован **распространительный вариант** (указательное слово в этом случае использовать нельзя). Почему распространительный?  Дело в том, что *войско* уже имеет определение *мощное*, поэтому придаточное предложение просто продолжает заданную тему (**это** войско....).

Можно указать **на стилистическую неточность**: определительное предложение **обычно** следует после определяемого слова. Конечно, инверсия соответствует общей структуре заданного предложения. И по правилу  Розенталя "слова *который, какой* должны замещать **ближайшее** к ним существительное в форме того же рода и числа", но предложение сложное, распространенное, поэтому смысл всё-таки частично затемняется.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня утверждение без местоимения выглядит естественнее. Добавление местоимения "то" ограничивает смысл указанием на "то самое" войско (которого боялись), снимая подразумеваемый второй смысл - причины "боязни": "такое,  что его боялись" (=такое, которого).

Answer (score 0):

Без цитирования всей пламенной речи не обойтись:

> Про пролитую кровь наш народ плохо помнит. Зато помнит скромного
>   начальника, который часов от Буре не носил и дворцов себе не строил.
>   И, в отличие от нынешних, ходил в одежде простого солдата. И никаких
>   себе богатств за время правления не нажил – разительный контраст с
>   нынешними, не правда ли? Вдобавок этот скромный товарищ в солдатском
>   френче страшную войну выиграл, могучую империю построил, мощное войско
>   создал, которого весь мир боялся, включая Америку. Гигантские заводы
>   возвел, новые города. Атомную бомбу сделал. Боевые ракеты.

Утверждаю, что не к войску мощному чувство боязни относится, а к скромному начальнику и товарищу в солдатском френче, который выиграл, построил, создал. Которого весь мир якобы боялся. Ведь после точки — опять про него: возвел, сделал. Точек многовато, и это сбивает.

Comment: С исторической точки зрения следовало бы утверждать, что мир боялся именно "скромного начальника", вероятно, автор именно это хотел сказать,  но грамматически никак это не следует из текста.

Comment: Она и смущала потому, что немного корява.